# How to implement mutations using nreco.graphql in dotnet application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, graphql, nreco

I am very new to Graphql and trying to implement mutations in dotnet using nreco.graphql, as of now there are no errors in the project files , when I tried to execute the mutation query am getting below error message. It says the input format what we are passing is not valid but I verified it many times and there is no error in it. So please help me to resolve the issue.

Query:
mutation($TestValue:TestInput!) {
ActivateInactivateUser(data:$TestValue) {
Status
}
}

Query Variables:
{
"TestValue": {
"UserID": "5",
"UserName": "Test",
"Status": "Inactive"
}
}

Error message:
Variable '$TestValue' is invalid. Unable to parse input as a 'TestInput' type. Did you provide a List or Scalar value accidentally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am very new to Graphql and trying to implement mutations in dotnet using nreco.graphql, as of now there are no errors in the project file

As far as I know, NReco.GraphQL based on engine Graph.Net. When it comes to mutation queries - you can check the docs from Graph.Net team [here](https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/mutations)

> Error message: Variable '$TestValue' is invalid. Unable to parse input as a 'TestInput' type. Did you provide a List or Scalar value accidentally

Did you set up an appropriate model for the method "ActivateInactivateUser"?
You ought to add sth like this:

> public class TestInputType : InputObjectGraphType